# Convert a cache object to HashMap

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, lru

I have a memory cache class that I use for storing the `Product` objects and the number of the items sold.

```
public class MemoryCache<K, V> {

    private long timeToLive;
    private LRUMap lruMap;

    /**
     * custom class that stores the cache value
     * and the timestamp for the last access
     */
    protected class CacheObject {

        public long lastAccessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        public V value;

        protected CacheObject(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param timeToLive    this is the permitted period of time for an object to live since
     *                      they are last accessed.
     *
     *                      <p>
     * @param timerInterval For the expiration of items use the timestamp of the last access
     *                      and in a separate thread remove the items when the time to live
     *                      limit is reached. This is nice for reducing memory pressure for
     *                      applications that have long idle time in between accessing the
     *                      cached objects. We have disabled the cleanup for this case scenario
     *
     *                      <p>
     * @param maxItems      Cache will keep most recently used items if we will try to add more
     *                      items then max specified. The Apache common collections have an LRUMap,
     *                      which, removes the least used entries from a fixed size map
     */
    public MemoryCache(long timeToLive, final long timerInterval, int maxItems) {

        this.timeToLive = timeToLive * 1000;

        lruMap = new LRUMap(maxItems);

        if (this.timeToLive > 0 && timerInterval > 0) {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(timerInterval * 1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }

                        /*
                         * clean the objects from the cache that has reached
                         * the timeToLive period after the last access.
                         * */
                        cleanup();
                    }
                }
            });

            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();
        }
    }


    /**
     * insert a new key and value inside the cache memory
     *
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public void put(K key, V value) {

        synchronized (lruMap) {

            if (key == null) {
                return;
            }

            /**
             * we have reached the max. size of items decided for the cache
             * and hence, we are not allowed to add more items for now. We
             * will need for the cache cleaning to add further items.
             */
            if (lruMap.isFull()) {
                return;
            }

            lruMap.put(key, new CacheObject(value));
        }
    }


    /**
     * retrieve the cache object from the memory using the key
     *
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public V get(K key) {

        synchronized (lruMap) {

            MapIterator iterator = lruMap.mapIterator();

            K k = null;
            V v = null;

            CacheObject o = null;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                k = (K) iterator.next();
                v = (V) iterator.getValue();

                Product product = (Product) k;
                Product product1 = (Product) key;

                if (product.getProductId().equalsIgnoreCase(product1.getProductId())) {
                    o = (CacheObject) v;
                }
            }

            if (o == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                o.lastAccessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return o.value;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * remove a cache object from the memory using the key
     *
     * @param key
     */
    public void remove(K key) {

        synchronized (lruMap) {
            lruMap.remove(key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * find the size of the memory cache
     *
     * @return size of the cache
     */
    public int size() {

        synchronized (lruMap) {
            return lruMap.size();
        }
    }


    /**
     * we will look after the cache objects with a certain time interval
     * that has stayed in the memory inactively more than the time to live
     * period and remove them iteratively.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void cleanup() {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ArrayList<K> deleteKey = null;

        synchronized (lruMap) {

            MapIterator iterator = lruMap.mapIterator();

            deleteKey = new ArrayList<K>((lruMap.size() / 2) + 1);

            K key = null;
            CacheObject object = null;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                key = (K) iterator.next();
                object = (CacheObject) iterator.getValue();

                if (object != null && (now > (object.lastAccessed + timeToLive))) {
                    deleteKey.add(key);
                }
            }
        }

        for (K key : deleteKey) {

            synchronized (lruMap) {
                lruMap.remove(key);
            }

            Thread.yield();
        }
    }

    /**
     * convert the cache full of items to regular HashMap with the same
     * key and value pair
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Map<Product, Integer> convertToMap() {

        synchronized (lruMap) {

            Map<Product, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            MapIterator iterator = lruMap.mapIterator();

            K k = null;
            V v = null;

            CacheObject o = null;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                k = (K) iterator.next();
                v = (V) iterator.getValue();

                Product product = (Product) k;

                // this fails right here
                int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(v));

                map.put(product, value);
            }

            return map;
        }
    }

}
```

Inside the API class, it's introduced as,

```
MemoryCache<Product, Integer> cache = new MemoryCache<>(1800, 500, 10000);
```

I store the product data with the items sold in the API class,

```
cache.put(product, 0);
```

The product class defined below,

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "productId")
    private String productId;

    @Column(name = "stockId")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "stock_timestamp")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;


    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String productId, Timestamp requestTimestamp, String id, Timestamp timestamp, int quantity) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.id = id;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


   // getter, setter 

   // equals and hasCode 

   // toString
}
```

The `convertToMap` method in the `MemoryCache` class takes the caches storages and turns that into `HashMap`. The method has a bug in the line where I try to store an `int` as value.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(v));
```

I have a screenshot for the debugging session.

[image]

As you see, I need to get the values (ie 1000, 100) and put that as the `value` of the intended `HashMap`. What's the correct way to write the `convertToMap` method for the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in your `LruMap` key is of type `Product` but value is of type `MemoryCache$CacheObject` not `Integer`.

So you need to change you code to

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(v.value)); //Assuming v is of type MemoryCache$CacheObject
```

Or you can even use this

```
Integer value = (Integer) v.value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

You know, I find the bug right after I posted in the forum myself while I spend a few hours earlier looking into it. My take away is when you write your problem in a clear manifesto, you solved a major part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are designed to avoid casts and so to make the code more robust but your way of using generics defeats it in a some way.
Your issue illustrates that perfectly :

```
MapIterator iterator = lruMap.mapIterator(); // no type associated to the iterator
// ....
k = (K) iterator.next(); // unsafe conversion
v = (V) iterator.getValue();    // unsafe conversion
Product product = (Product) k; // unsafe conversion    
// this fails right here
int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(v)); // how to be sure that v is an Integer ?
```

`LRUMap` and `MapIterator` that are probably custom classes **have to** be generic classes that relies on similarly to `MemoryCache<K,V>` to make the whole thing consistent.
In the same way this method specified in the generic class is clearly an abuse of the typing of the map. You pass from generic types declared in the class to `Product` and `Integer`  :

```
public class MemoryCache<K, V> {
    //..
    public Map<Product, Integer> convertToMap() {}
    //..
}
```

Finally it makes your `MemoryCache` designed to work only with `Product` and `Integer` as `K`, `V` concrete type. In this case, generics are useless, you have to remove them.
If later you want/need to get a more generic solution, go further in the generic application and you should finish with a `convertToMap()` defined as :

```
public Map<K, V> convertToMap() {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I find the solution for the problem.

Comment: @Arefe You are welcome. That is a very important point. If the solution that you found relies on random casts, your cache would be really not robust and consistent. I updated to explain more. Defining a cache class with some design/runtime issues is really something to avoid.